# Como fazer dois loops para o mesmo código só ir variando a coluna dos cursos e as colunas das questões?

Tags: r, loop, table, for, dplyr

Tenho um data.frame com muitos códigos nas linhas e muitas colunas de perguntas, estou fazendo a **frequência simples de cada pergunta** gostaria de saber como faço para variar os cursos e as perguntas de uma vez, sem precisar ficar repetindo mil vezes manualmente o código que eu gerei?

```
cursos <- c(rep(12671,10)) 
pergunta1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,2,1)
pergunta2 <- c(1,1,2,1,3,4,2,1,3,3)
df <- data.frame(cursos,pergunta1,pergunta2)
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 3):

Acho que uma maneira melhor do que usar loops é usar pacotes como o `dplyr` e `reshape`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

df %>%
  melt(id="cursos") %>%
  dcast(value ~ variable + cursos, fun.aggregate=length)

  value pergunta1_12671 pergunta2_12671
1     1               2               4
2     2               2               2
3     3               1               3
4     4               1               1
5     5               1               0
6     6               1               0
7     7               2               0
```

A função `melt` transforma os dados em formato longo, deixando tudo em três colunas: a primeira para os cursos, a segunda para as perguntas e a última para a contagem destas perguntas.

A seguir, utilizei a função `dcast`, junto com a opção `fun.aggregate=length`, para contar a quantidade de vezes que cada pergunta aparece.